# How does $f$ change with the increasing of $\sigma$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

The $f=\int^{+\infty}_{0}x^{\lambda}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$, and $\lambda$ is a positive constant value, $m=1000$, how does $f$ change with the increasing of $\sigma$. (if $\sigma^2$ changes from 20 to 200)

How to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Take the derivative of w.r.t. $\sigma$ and see what you get (i.e. under what conditions is the derivative positive or negative)

Comment: Shouldn't the integral be taken from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: A heuristic view is that when $\lambda>1$, the increased probability of large values with increased $\sigma$ has a larger impact than the increased probability of small values with increased $\sigma$, so that the whole thing increases with $\sigma$. When $\lambda=1$ you can just do the computation explicitly.

Comment: (Cont.) When $0<\lambda<1$ you have the opposite effect of the former for a certain range of $\sigma$. But eventually you will reach a turning point where $X>2000$ takes on appreciable probability, which cannot be compensated for by the continued increase in the probability of small values. At this point it should turn around.

Comment: Why don't you want to differentiate? That's the standard way.

Comment: thanks guys, but it seems not easy to take the derivarive w.r.t. $\sigma$.

Comment: It's not really all that hard to differentiate with respect to $\sigma$, but it's not obvious to me that you get a particularly enlightening expression out of it. To be specific, differentiation results in a negative contribution from the interval $(m-\sigma,m+\sigma)$ (where we extend the integral to $\mathbb{R}$ by defining the integrand to be zero for negative $x$) and a positive contribution off of that interval. I don't see how to analytically find a root of this quantity.

Answer (score 0):

If the integral were taken from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, then the integral equals to $\newcommand{\expect}{\mathbf{E}} \expect\left(X^\lambda\right)$ where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(m, \sigma^2)$.

So obviously when $\lambda=1$, it is nothing but the expected value of $X$, hence it stays the same, the value is the mean, $m$.

If $\lambda=2$, then it's $\newcommand{\var}{\mathbf{Var}}\expect X^2 = \var(X) + \left(\expect X\right)^2 = \var(X) + m^2$, hence it's increasing as $\sigma$ increases, since $\var(X) = \sigma^2$.

Comment: thanks, but you just give some special cases when $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=2$, how to prove it strictly?

Comment: i haven't solved that yet. but if i was right about the limit of the integral, i.e., it should be taken from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, $\lambda$ should be integers. .. ?? So the integral should be taken from $0$ to $\infty$? Then it's not true that $f=m$ for $\labmda=1$. You need to clarify this first, I think.

Comment: Pease note that (very close)

Comment: Oh, thx, I think i know how to prove that. please refer to another answer to your question of mine.

Answer (score 0):

First note that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\newcommand{\iitt}[2]{\int_{#1}^{#2}}
f(\sigma) &=& \iitt{0}{\infty} x^\lambda \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}
\right) dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \iitt{-m/\sigma}{\infty} (\sigma y +m )^\lambda \exp(-y^2/2)dy.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now [leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) implies
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(\sigma) &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \iitt{-m/\sigma}{\infty} \lambda (\sigma y + m)^{\lambda-1} \exp(-y^2/2) dy
- 0^\lambda \exp(-m^2/2\sigma^2) \cdot \frac{d}{d\sigma} (-m/\sigma)
\\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \iitt{-m/\sigma}{\infty} \lambda (\sigma y + m)^{\lambda-1} \exp(-y^2/2) dy > 0
\end{eqnarray*}
since $\lambda (\sigma y + m)^{\lambda-1} \exp(-y^2/2)>0$ for all $y>-m/\sigma$.

Therefore as long as $\lambda>0$, regardless of the values of $\lambda$ and $m$, $f(\sigma)$ is an increasing function of $\sigma$.

This proves that it is not true that $f(\sigma)$ is decreasing for $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

By the way, when $\lambda = 0$, it becomes
$$
f(\sigma) = \mathbf{Prob}\{X\geq -m/\sigma\}
$$
where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Thus

- if $m=0$, $f(\sigma)$ is constant.
- if $m>0$, $-m/\sigma$ is an increasing function of $\sigma$, hence $f(\sigma)$ is a decreasing function of $\sigma$.
- if $m<0$, $-m/\sigma$ is a decreasing function of $\sigma$, hence $f(\sigma)$ is an increasing function of $\sigma$.

Comment: This approximation does not hold

Comment: You lost a factor of $y$ in $f'(\sigma)$, which leaves you with an indefinite sign. This indefinite sign is not merely an artifact of sending the lower endpoint of the original integral to $-\infty$ because after the change of variable the exact lower endpoint is $-m$.

Comment: Sorry, it is $-\sigma^{-1} m$, but the point stands: the integrand in the calculation for $f'(\sigma)$ does not have a definite sign. This is obvious because if it did then the same would be true when $\lambda=0$, in which case $f'(\sigma)$ becomes zero in the approximation you made with extending the domain of integration.

Comment: @Ian you're right. thx for pointing that out. i'll try to correct my answer.

Comment: Your edit did not fix my objection, which was that $\frac{d}{d\sigma}((\sigma y + m)^\lambda)=\lambda(\sigma y + m)^{\lambda-1} y$. (In the regime the OP is interested in, replacing $-m/\sigma$ by $-\infty$ was actually a reasonable approximation.) Your procedure here is simply not salvageable in the case $\lambda>0$.

Comment: You might be able to do something in the case $\lambda \geq 1$ by integrating by parts with $u=(\sigma y + m)^{\lambda-1}$ and $dv=ye^{-y^2/2} dx$. In the case $\lambda \in (0,1)$ I think this doesn't help (it results in a $\infty - \infty$ form, which requires some massaging with limits to deal with, and so is probably harder than the expression at hand).

Comment: @Ian you're right. let me correct my answer following your advice. probably later today.

Answer (score -1):

Taking the derivative

$$f'(\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma^4}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}((x-\mu)^2 - \sigma^2)e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$

Now let's take the case of $\mu=0$. This simplifies down to comparing the values of the two integrals 
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\lambda+2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \hspace{20 pt} I_2=\sigma^2\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\lambda}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$

$$ I_1 = \sigma^{\lambda+3}2^{\frac{\lambda+1}{2}}\Gamma\left( \frac{\lambda+3}{2}\right) \hspace{20 pt} I_2 = \sigma^{\lambda+3}2^{\frac{\lambda-1}{2}}\Gamma\left( \frac{\lambda+1}{2}\right)$$
$$\implies \frac{I_1}{I_2} = \lambda + 1$$

In other words, this derivative is always positive for $\lambda > 0$, so it is always an increasing function of $\sigma$. I'm not sure yet how this changes in the $\mu\neq 0$ case.

Comment: the μ should be a large value (like 1000) compare to the $\sigma^2$ (like 20 to 200)